# Images showing with activityIndicator as images is being refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on VirtualTourist project on Udacity and we are required to display images as the images are being refreshed through a Flickr Client. Currently my implementation is such that the refresh will only show once the images are fully downloaded. The project requires such that the images are shown as an when they are downloaded, and while the downloading is happening, an activity indicator is displayed instead.

My code as follows:

```
 @IBAction func newCollectionButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
        print("FETCHING NEW COLLECTION...")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.photos.removeAll()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            print("Reload Data newColVC")
        }
        for items in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! {
            context.delete(items as! NSManagedObject)
        }

        loadPhotos()
    }

func loadPhotos() {
        newColActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        newColActivityIndicator.isHidden = false
        newCollectionButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        newCollectionButton.alpha = 0.4

        FlickrClient.sharedInstance.getPhotos(pin.coordinate.latitude as AnyObject, lon: pin.coordinate.longitude as AnyObject, { (results, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if results != nil {

                    for result in results! {
                        let picture = Photo(pin: self.pin, imageData: result as NSData, context: self.context)
                        self.photos.append(picture)
                    }

                    do {
                        try self.delegate.stack?.saveContext()
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Error saving context in loadPhotos(): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.newColActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.newColActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
                        self.newCollectionButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        self.newCollectionButton.alpha = 1.0
                        print("Reload Data loadPhotos")

                    }

                }
            }
        })

    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageViewCell

        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = false

        let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

        if let photoImage = photo.imageData {
            print("PhotoImage present")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: photoImage as Data)
            }

        } else {
            print("PhotosImage don have")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Some advice here is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the question in this question?

Answer (score 0):

So firstly when you tap `newCollectionButton` you are removing all the data stored in core data as well as removing all those which are being displayed in collection view. So at this moment, collection view doesnot have anything to display. as a result it should be empty showing nothing.

Now, i think your `loadPhotos` methods returns the collection of photos from flicker which you add it to your local array and coredata. datasource of collection view must be using data from `photos` array.

You remove the activity indicator and then reload the collection view. At this point, you already have the necessary data for the images to be shown available. So `cellForItemAt` retrives data from local array, and create image and displays it. Maybe this process is happenning so fast, that your `cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` & `cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` is executing much faster.

Since your question is unclear, & your `loadPhotos` fetches collection of photos data, if you want that activityIndicator to be shown in each cell, until all the image gets downloaded, you can

- Remove just imagedata present in `Photo` object stored in local/coredata
- make cell to show activity indicator if there is no image data present in each cell
- reloadData() so that activity indicator starts
- call `loadPhotos`
- After downloading all photos, clear photo array, store downloaded Photos in array and call reloadData() so that all the images gets displayed.